# default mysql select order

Tags: mysql

I've changed the ID field of several rows. Now "SELECT * FROM table" returns me the rows in the original order.

Example:

```
ID NAME
1 JOSJ
12 Matt
3 Tom
```

How do I get them to display in the correct order by default? I'm not talking about a simple "ORDER BY", although it's probably as simple. The table needs to be rearranged somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default order in the table is just that, the default. Your database will not get confused if they are out of order. You could insert them into a new table using an `ORDER BY`, but that's a lot more work than just adding an `ORDER BY` to your query

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY ID
```

You can use the command below to change the ordering, but after an `INSERT` or `DELETE` the ordering will be changed back to the order they were inserted

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ORDER BY columnname ASC;
```

Comment: My question clearly stated that I was not looking for that. I need to know how to resort them so they appear in the right order BY DEFAULT.

Comment: @Jerry That's not a permanent option unless you create a  new table and even then, it's not a good option.

Comment: The text came later! However the alter command is what I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

SQL does not guarantee any default ordering. A conforming SQL implementation could randomly sort all rows before returning them, for example.

Bottom line is, **If you want a certain ordering - specify it in the query.** That's all you can ask for.

Comment: .. And add an index if you use that order often.